# Shopify Emails being set by SendGrid with Neutral SPF

Tags: dns, shopify, sendgrid, spf

I have my domain on google domains which is pointed to Shopify. (A and CNAME). I don't have any other settings on the Domains DNS.
I don't have any email hosting and I just setup one email on google domains to forward to a freshdesk email address.
The strange thing is that when an email goes out from the Shopify store (order confirmation email for example) the email gets sent via sendgrid.info
I don't have a SendGrid account and have to idea how they fit into the picture.
The problem is that several emails go undelivered because the SPF is Neutral.

If I change the Shopify email address to another domain it switches back to using Shopify's mail servers but when I change it back it goes back to sendgrid.
I've spent hours talking to Shopify and they couldn't give me an answer.

Hoping someone on here could figure out what is going on.

Comment: This sounds like a question for Shopify support. Without any code there's not much anyone here can do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is nothing related to programming in it.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is create a SPF record entry in your domain DNS records and add shopify in SPF records.

```
v=spf1 include:shops.shopify.com ~all
```

More details about how to do this is explained clearly in the below link.
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/intro-to-shopify/initial-setup/setup-your-email

Emails are going to spam, because the various email service providers are not able to verify that shopify is allowed to send email on your domains behalf.